# Executing Drools Rules Engine on DB for remove duplicates

Tags: drools, rdbms, rules, rule-engine

The question I have is not around drools or rules engine but I have a specific usecase where I am planning to use rule engine. I read through all the questions and googling but was unable to get the best fit. Below is my query

we have a crawler engine which pumps the data in DB. since data is huge we often have fewer duplicate entries. Currently the rules are tightly bound in DB Tables and using complex queries. I thought of having rules engine which would perform on top on the table but I am unable to attain it via rules.  Am I missing anything ? or my understanding is wrong.

1. First question is ,  using rules engine a right approach?
2. Second is , If rules can be used. I could not find an approach on firing rules on Array.

Questions may be naive but I still am not finding a solution.

Comment: Removing duplicates from an array is not something where you'd use a rule engine. - And "we often have fewer duplicate entries" is not a clear statement.

Comment: @laune : After our processing we have duplicate entries for few of the records.

Comment: Understood. This doesn't change my opinion: not a case for a rule engine. Comparing N array elements to each other is O(N^2), and a rule engine isn't going to reduce that.

Answer (score 0):

For what you described above Drools is really not a good fit. However depending exactly what you try to achieve you may find it useful. Instead of **removing** duplicates you can use a rule engine to **prevent the insertion** of duplicates. To achieve that you need to have a stateful session with your existing record-set in it, and you can write your own evaluation rules in Drools to mark incoming entries as duplicates. As a result of your execution you can decide whether this new entry should be saved or discarded as duplicate. What you should consider:

- Do you want to invest that much time/effort into this task?
- Do you really need a rule-engine, for example do you expect frequent changes in the validation logic?
- Would there be any issue with the performance of Drools? (the volume of your data or the frequency of the incoming records might exceed the capabilities of Drools)